# Custom build completed email alert in Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: email, build, alert, azure-devops

I want to send an email when the build is completed in Visual Studio Team Services. It will contain other information also, like code analysis.

How to do it?

Comment: There is nothing out there on Google on this, e.g. when searching `sending custom build completed email alert in visual studio team services`? You sure?

Comment: I couldn't find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code analysis result isn’t included in the email, also there isn’t the way to custom email alert in Visual Studio Team Services. [There](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/10221201-customize-email-output-of-alert-emails) is a related user voice.

You need to click Open Build Report in Web Access hyperlink to go to web access to get details result.